# Cannot find resource dictionaries

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

So the image below says everything. WPF cannot locate *some* of the xaml files. I have tried moving them around, to no avail. All of them have their Build Action set to Page and Custom Tool set to MSBuild:Compile. Don't know what I'm missing here.

[image: Errors Snapshot]

### EDIT

As requested, here are two sample xaml files. One of them works and the other one doesn't.

**GroupBox.xaml (working one)**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Shared.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<!-- SimpleStyles: GroupBox -->
<Style TargetType="GroupBox">
    <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="#4C4C4C"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupBox">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" 
                Background="{StaticResource LightBrush}"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="1" 
                CornerRadius="2,2,0,0" >
          <ContentPresenter Margin="4"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            ContentSource="Header" 
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" 
                Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}" 
                BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" 
                CornerRadius="0,0,2,2" >
          <ContentPresenter Margin="4" />
        </Border>
        </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Toolbox.xaml (doesn't work)**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:s="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type s:Toolbox}">
<Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type s:Toolbox}">
      <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
              Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
              Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
              SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
          <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
      </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel Margin="0,5,0,5"
                 ItemHeight="{Binding Path=ItemSize.Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=s:Toolbox}}"
                 ItemWidth="{Binding Path=ItemSize.Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=s:Toolbox}}"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

### EDIT 2

This may seem crazy, but changing `x:Class="DiagramDesigner.App"` to `x:Class="App"` fixed all the errors for me. Looks like VB.NET doesn't want me to specify namespace in that attribute.

Comment: Assume you've done a clean and rebuild? That always solves it for me with WPF

Comment: @Nico: That doesn't work for me. I have restarted VS too. Important to note that the problem is confined to *some* but not all files.

Comment: Are you using a network share or an external storage?

Comment: What are the contents of one of the files from a working one and a non-working one?

Comment: Please try one by one Resources Dictionary in a Sample Project. Check that is working or not.

Comment: What are the other errors? As you have 96 of them. Could you print screen the whole error list? As it might be related to contents having errors in those faulty dictionaries.

Comment: @Everyone: Please see edit 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark, but change `x:Class="DiagramDesigner.App` to `x:Class="App"`.

;-)

Comment: That's exactly the solution. How did you guess so accurately? :-)

Comment: @dotNET Of course feel free to answer your own question and I shall delete this farcical post. Or if you like you can mark mine as the answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

try adding resources as

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/DiagramDesigner;component/Resources/Themes/CommonThemes.xaml" />
```

or from code behind you can add as

```
 Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();

var resource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/DiagramDesigner;component/CultureDictionary.xaml");
```

Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = resource });

Comment: Exactly same result. Works for the ones for which it is working in the snapshot, shows error for others.

Comment: If, this style is not work in xaml then how can it work in Code Behind.

Comment: You were just confirming? Then is this an answer or a comment? Btw, I think your caps lock key might have been toggled during your last comment.